# Inviting new friends over

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Is there a link I can use to gather my friends from Facebook or Google Plus, so I can invite them to join Stack Overflow?

Comment: Like how facebook asks if you wanna invite friends from your email account when you register

Comment: Sure, just send them to http://stackoverflow.com.  No other link is needed.  Feel free to send that link to anyone you want to share it with.

Comment: thank you guys for the response ... I guess it does make sense now, that they wouldn't use that like how a social site wouls ...

Answer (score 9):

Yes:

### https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup

But note that there's no privileges gained from inviting, no address book sharing, nor any "social" feature involved.

The focus of the Stack Exchange network is on the content, not users.

It's almost better to use the link **https://stackoverflow.com/about**, so they arrive straight into the introductory page. As it explains what makes this sites so different from forums and social networks.

Comment: thank you for the response, I'll be sure to use the link you provided instead ...